# save mp4 video to device camera roll

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm starting with just an NSString that is a url to an .mp4 file, and from here I would like to have that video saved to the device camera roll. It seems I can only save .mov files, so I have to first convert the .mp4, but the few posts I've seen about this didn't help.

Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12):

You can save an mp4 file to the camera roll provided it uses [supported codecs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html). For example:

```
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://path/to/video.mp4"];

NSURLSessionTask *download = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:sourceURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceURL lastPathComponent]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:tempURL error:nil];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempURL.path, nil, NULL, NULL);
}];

[download resume];
```

Or, on iOS 6 and above:

```
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://path/to/video.mp4"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:sourceURL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceURL lastPathComponent]];
    [data writeToURL:tempURL atomically:YES];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempURL.path, nil, NULL, NULL);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, your solution seems to work perfectly in iOS 7, but I need to make it work in iOS 6.1+. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to download the file with `NSURLConnection` or a third party library. You'll still want to write it to a temp file and then call `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Comment: @SeanT, I added an iOS 6 example.

Comment: @jonahb Could you offer some advice on my [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965566/how-to-efficiently-write-large-files-to-disk-on-background-thread-swift) for handling large amounts of data. I'm interested in ensuring that saving data to a video file is handled correctly on a background thread. It almost appears that your solution might work but the implications of threading are not apparent. Thanks for your thoughts in advance.