# Sending data from disk to server without loading into ram on iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am working on an application that sometimes requires sending large files (500MB) or more to our servers. Generally the files will already be stored on disk and I will have the local file URL, is there a way I can create an NSMutableRequest without having to first load **all the data** from disk into NSData?

It would be nice just to read a few MB at a time from the disk, send it off, and then repeat until its all gone. What is the best / most efficient way to go about this?

**Edit**

Basically if I had a 10GB video I wanted to upload, I would never be able to fit all of it into NSData before the system terminated my app due to memory constraints.

Comment: Unless the device has some dedicated hardware connected to both the "disk" and the radio, I don't think it is possible to send data out "without loading it into RAM".

Comment: Ya sorry should have specified without having to load it all in ram at once, just a couple MB at a time

Comment: Basically if I had a 10GB video I wanted to upload, I would never be able to fit that into NSData before the system terminated my app due to memory constraints.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965566/how-to-efficiently-write-large-files-to-disk-on-background-thread-swift

Comment: It seems to be about **writing** to disk, but the same or similar API should help

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look

Comment: @NicolasMiari if you posted that as an answer I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to read your large, local file in bits and send it over the network. You can do that using the foundation class `NSInputStream`.

Sample code from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD) (Objective-C):

```
- (void)setUpStreamForFile:(NSString *)path {
    // iStream is NSInputStream instance variable
    iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:path];
    [iStream setDelegate:self];
    [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [iStream open];
}
```

in **Swift 3**, that would be something like this:

```
func setUpStream(forFile path: String) -> InputStream? {
    guard let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path) else {
        return nil
    }
    stream.delegate = self
    stream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    stream.open()

    return stream
}
```

*(You will also need to adopt the protocol [NSStreamDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstreamdelegate?language=objc), but this is enough to get oyu started I guess...)*